# How to divide percentage of a sector with different colors in justgage dashboard

Tags: justgage

I am already using JustGage java script to plot donut sectors.
Currently I am drawing sector with single color. e.g. If it is 95% then fill green and if below 95% fill red.
In my requirement I need to plot 40% with different colors.
For example, 20% green, 10% red and 10% orange.
How can I do this using JustGage script.

Comment: I am just exploring JustGage API to plot this option. Currently I am drawing sector with single color. e.g. If it is 95% then fill green and if below 95% fill red.

Comment: In my requirement I need to plot 40% with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `levelColors : [  "#f00", "#0f0",  "#00f" ]`

or

```
customSectors :  [
    { color: '#3a0', lo: 100, hi: 999 },
    { color: '#fa0', lo: 80, hi: 100 },
    { color: '#f10', lo: 0, hi: 80 }
]
```

It's works well for me :)

More info:

http://justgage.com/

http://justgage.com/examples/